# Remove sub folder name from URL

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
http://example.com/portal/reports/data.php?id=2
```

In this URL I want to hide portal folder in the url/:

```
http://example.com/reports/data.php?id=2
```

How can I achieve this using mod_rewrite?

I used online generators and Researched in Many Stack Website for doing the rewrite rules but none can remove a piece of text from the URL But None Worked For Me

Comment: "I want to hide reports folder" - In your example you appear to have _hidden_ the `portal` folder, not the `reports` folder? Please include what you have tried and the contents of your existing `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Yea I Wanna Hide  the portal folder , Modified The Question !

Comment: But what have you tried

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *permanently* "remove" the `/portal` prefix from the stated URL, you could do something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove "/portal" prefix from stated URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule ^portal/(reports/data\.php)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite the request back to the actual file
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule ^reports/data\.php$ portal/$0 [END]
```

The `$0` and `$1` backreferences refer back to the captured groups in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*. `$0` refers to the entire match.

The query string (ie. `id=2`) is passed through by default.

Assumptions:

1. You are already linking to the URL *without* the `/portal` prefix in your internal links.
2. There are no other `.htaccess` files in any of the subdirectories (eg. `/portal` or `/portal/reports`)
3. Using Apache 2.4 (as opposed to Apache 2.2).

Comment: I Have Tried This Similar Its Not Working !

Comment: @RamGowda What do you mean by "Similar"? What do you mean by "Not Working" exactly? Are you getting an error? Undesirable response? _Nothing_? What URL are you requesting? What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? What version of Apache are you using? Is this your own local development server or a cloud/live server? Do you have access to the main server config?